# SWT MouseDown event too dominant for custom selecting controls

Tags: java, swt, mouseevent, multipleselection

I have made the UI/Editor you can see in the picture below. The Text is displayed by `StyledText`s. The black lines are custom borders that are in fact `Label`s with lines drawn on them.

[image: unselected]

[image: selected]

Now my goal is to provide a selection that allows the user to select the `Control`s to delete them or add others to them. The second image shows a example selection. So started with all kinds of `MouseEvent`s this is more complicated than I initially thought.

When the `MouseDown` event is fired on any `Control` I am not able to track any other `Control`s that the user wants to select because the `MouseMove` event contains the same control that fired the `MouseDown` event until the mouse gets released. I need to track to ongoing selection to provide the visual feedback for the selected `Control`s. The code below shows a minimal example to demonstrate the behavior.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setText("Stackoverflow");

        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        SelectionListener listener = new SelectionListener();

        StyledText text = new StyledText(comp, SWT.NONE);
        text.setText("first text");
        attachListener(text, listener);
        text = new StyledText(comp, SWT.NONE);
        text.setText("second text");
        attachListener(text, listener);


        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void attachListener(Control control, Listener listener) {
        if(control != null && !control.isDisposed()){
            control.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
            control.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, listener);
            control.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, listener);
            control.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, listener);
        }
    }

    static class SelectionListener implements Listener {

        Event lastEvent = null;

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            switch(event.type){

            case SWT.MouseDown:
                lastEvent = event;
                break;

            case SWT.MouseMove:
                if(lastEvent != null){
                    if(event.widget == lastEvent.widget)
                        System.out.println("the same!!!");
                    else
                        System.out.println("not the same!!!");
                }
                break;

            case SWT.MouseEnter:
                //this also does not fire when MouseDown is fired
                System.out.println("entering");
                break;

            case SWT.MouseUp:
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So basically I am reaching out for help. Maybe there is a better/simpler way to achieve this. I was also trying to figure out how swt is doing this in tables or other controls that support multiple selection. But its hard to find the specific code or they call native methods for nativ controls such as tables. So if anyone has an idea please share.

Comment: You want to select multiple sections by dragging mouse over sections right?

Comment: Yes, over the named controls (Labels and StyledTexts). Currently working on an approach where I send a MouseUp event myself when I leave a certain control, after that all other events are coming through again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. You can post a `MouseUp` event yourself. After that all events are coming through again. The only difficult part is to distinguish between your own custom event and a normal user/system event. I was able create/find some criteria to identify the custom event. The following code/doc explains this in more detail:

```
/**
     * Sets up a custom {@code SWT.MouseUp} event and fires it. This is needed because a {@code SWT.MouseDown} is consuming all
     * other events until a {@code SWT.MouseUp} event is fired. This means that it is not possible to get a e.g. 
     * {@code SWT.MouseEnter} event when entering a certain StyledText which is needed for selection. Therefore a custom {@code SWT.MouseUp} 
     * event is fired to simulate the releasing of the button on system level so that all other events can come through again. The real problem here
     * is to distinguish between the custom event for simulation and a normal event produced by the user. Firing the event via Display.post(Event)
     * does not fire the handed over event parameter. The system actually creates a new event instance. Therefore 2 criteria are used to distinguish the custom event:
     *  <ul>
     *      <ol>1. The selection can only be started by dragging a border control. 
     *          A {@code SWT.DragDetect} event starts the hole selection process. All events coming in before this event are ignored.</ol>
     *      <ol>2. The actual distinguishing of the {@code SWT.MouseUp} is performed on the cursor coordinates and the referenced/dragged {@code widget}.
     *          The dragging event has to be started on this widget.</ol>
     *  </ul>
     * @param the starting {@code SWT.DragDetect} event
     * @see #isCustomMouseUpEvent(Event)
     */
    private void fireCustomMouseUpEvent(Event dragDetectEvent){
        customMouseUpEvent = new Event();
        customMouseUpEvent.type = SWT.MouseUp;
        customMouseUpEvent.button = 1; //left mouse button
        customMouseUpEvent.widget = dragDetectEvent.widget;

        if(dragDetectEvent.widget instanceof Control){
            startingControl = (Control) dragDetectEvent.widget;
            //get cursor location relative to widget to be comparable later with the event fired by the system
            Point cursorLocation = startingControl.toControl(startingControl.getDisplay().getCursorLocation());
            customMouseUpEvent.x = cursorLocation.x;
            customMouseUpEvent.y = cursorLocation.y;
        }

        /*
         * note: set attributes like Event.data or Event.x are not present 
         * in the actually firing event. SWT or the system is creating a complete new
         * event instance without those manually added information.
         */
//      mouseUpEvent.data = SELECTION_START_EVENT_IDENTIFIER;
        if(dragDetectEvent.widget.getDisplay().post(customMouseUpEvent))
            System.out.println("custom MouseUp event fired!");
    }

    private boolean isCustomMouseUpEvent(Event event) {
        return customMouseUpEvent != null && event.widget == customMouseUpEvent.widget && 
                customMouseUpEvent.x == event.x && customMouseUpEvent.y == event.y;
    }
```

Comment: Just want elaborate on this. While it works on Windows it does not work on Linux (Ubuntu). Found a way to implement a custom selection with the DragAndDrop (DND) mechanism in SWT. This is also used in SWT (at least for the StyledText) for the scrolling implementation (selecting text and auto scroll). There is also dead code in the StyledText class implementing the scrolling with mouse events which at first confused me until I debuged and found that this code never gets called (at least not in Windows) .